# Merging two OCR trained data

Tags: java, linux, ocr

Im trying to recognise an Image(form) and convert into text,currently using the egg.trained data from google "tesseract-ocr" and this works fine for printed characters and for manually written one(written by person manually) i developed a trained data,and this works fine for the characters i trained. nOw i want to merge these two trained data (tesseract-ocr + my own trained data) so i can recognise both handwritten and printed characters in a single form, please let me know how to merge these two files into one.

Answer (score 5):

No need to merge them. Tesseract 3.02 supports recognition of multiple languages -- you can specify, for instance, "egg+eng+blah" as value for the -l option.

Comment: thx for the reply, im using Tesseract 3.01 that does not support the feature u mentioned, is there any way i can do the same in version 3.1 or how do i download the tesseract, guess its not offically out.

Comment: You can check out the source from http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/checkout and build the 3.02 executable.

Comment: Thx for your time ,I tried using SVN and try to download but it says doesnt exist.
Command: Export  
Error: URL 'http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/%20tesseract-ocr-read-only'  
Error:  doesn't exist  
Completed!: