# How to use multiple language support on Android with Tesseract?

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, multilingual

I'm trying to make use of Tesseract TessbaseApi and I want to use two languages so that I can recognize for example English and Greek characters together.

I found that Tesseract 3.02 supports the recognition of multiple languages ([Merging two OCR trained data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350434/merging-two-ocr-trained-data)).

But how can I use this in Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set via the `init` method:

```
baseApi.init(dataPath, "eng+ell");
```