# Is there a way to detect multiple languages from a scanned image?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to convert scanned images to text from **tesseract ocr** and it is working great except that my images has two languages in it and the **tesseract** is unable to detect both at once. I can either convert all the images to English (with Arabic being showed as some garbage value not roman Arabic), and vice versa if I convert it to Arabic (that is I get all the text in Arabic, with the English ones as Garbage).

I have tried to detect the exported text with langDetect but given the characters and ASCII are of English letters I'm unable to detect it.

I am sharing a sample of the [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u0Pw.jpg), it would be great if someone can help me get a better solution of the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379781/tesseract-how-to-run-tesseract-with-multiple-languages-one-time/27602888

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tesseract: How to run tesseract with multiple languages one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379781/tesseract-how-to-run-tesseract-with-multiple-languages-one-time)

Answer (score 0):

Just Update your code with this

```
lang = 'eng+ara'
```

ara stands for `ara.traineddata`.

One more thing: arabic trained data might not be in the tesseract so download the `ara.traineddata` from git and paste it in `tessdata` folder of tesseract ocr.

I am also giving you the link for this traineddata: [link](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/ara.traineddata).